# symfony3 same validation for model and admin form

Tags: php, symfony, validation, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin

I'm using FOS User Bundle and [Sonata Admin Bundle](http://It's%20http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/index.html).
I have validation in model like:

```
 //src\AppBundle\Entity\User.php
 //class User extends BaseUser
 /**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\NotBlank(
 *     message = "xxx"
 * )
 * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="text")
 */
private $address;
```

I want to use same validation in my AdminController - is there any option how to inherit model's validation? Now I must do it like:

```
//src\AppBundle\Admin\UserAdmin.php
//class UserAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
public function validate(ErrorElement $errorElement, $object)
{
    $errorElement
        ->with('address')
        ->assertNotBlank()
        ->end();
}
```

Comment: Can you describe us which `AdminBundle` are you using?

Comment: Sorry, updated question

Comment: Not understanding your validate function - can't you just call the Symfony validator on your entity and call it a day?

Comment: @JasonRoman how do you mean? I thought that validate() is called automatically on entity, but it's not.

Comment: Oh maybe it does with the SonataAdminBundle, sorry I didn't read that part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using custom Validation Groups.

First group you Validation Constraints.

From the example you have provided

```
 //src\AppBundle\Entity\User.php
 //class User extends BaseUser
 /**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\NotBlank(
 *     message = "xxx",
 *     groups={"reg"}
 * )
 * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="text")
 */
private $address;
```

Next define a protected $formOptions property in your admin class, like so

```
//src\AppBundle\Admin\UserAdmin.php
//class UserAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
    protected $formOptions = array(
    'validation_groups' => 'reg'
    );
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working, but why is here http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/conditional_validation.html#troubleshooting - "There should not be any validation_groups defined for the form"?

Comment: as the subheading says it's for troubleshooting when the inline Validation ( if any ) doesn't work .